# Defining constants in an interface class to avoid accidently missing out public static final directives

Tags: java

While we all understand that to declare constants (for brevity reasons) in an interface as opposed to a class is evil because it pollutes namespace for and post Java 5 you can use static imports to reduce verbosity (Effective Java Item 17). However, a colleague of mine pointed out that a developer can miss out declaring the variable as final (public and static can be discounted as absence of it would be a compilation error) when defining it in a class whereas they come implicitly for interfaces. Any arguments for/against it? I guess this might have been discussed at length before as it seems pretty rudimentary, but my google-fu is not helping me today :). Would appreciate if someone can opine here or point me to a place where this may have already been discussed.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The interface file thus defined will not be used in the class hierarchy of its clients but will purely serve to house constants.

Comment: I like to use inner interfaces (= public interface inside class ) for this to avoid both disadvantages (Pollution and accidentally making the const variable). I don't have links to discussions, though.

Comment: Thats a nice approach as well, though not sure how readable it would look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a post Java 5 SDK, then why not evaluate Enums instead of using interfaces to define, public static constants. Nevertheless, nothing wrong in the approach though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think defining constants in an interface is evil. If anything, implementing a constants-interface in a public class is evil.
However, this leaves us with a lot of other good options

- You can extend the interface to add more constants

  - For instance, an interface defines well known property names. Then you can have a sub-interface that adds properties specific to your implementation.
  - Constants-classes usually have a private constructor, which makes subclassing impossible.
- Not all classes of my implementation are part of the (public) API. I don't think it actually matters if an internal class implements a constants-interface.
- Let's say a method expects constants as method arguments:
   `myXmlProcessor.setProperty(XMLOptions.VALIDATING, true)`

  - How do you know where to get the constants from? Often, there are several constants-classes, which leaves the risk to use the wrong one.
  - `myXmlProcessor.setProperty(MyXMLProcessor.VALIDATING, true)`: here you *know* it is right.
- If you have a class hierarchy and the base class implements the constants-interface, they are automatically available to the subclasses. Again, less room for mistakes.

Comment: I had some concerns on the other options that you mentioned: 1. Extension or hierarchy is not applicable here. This class houses items like MAX_ROWS returned from all DAO's. There is no common base class from where they all extend and hence the need for housing it in its own class. 2. I am not using this to expose public API, but to keep code readable. 3. The method arguments can be easily got right by using enums rather than confusing primitives like Strings.  4. Again, not having a hierarchy.

Comment: 1) What is "here" and "this class"? You give no context in your question. If you ask generic questions, please expect generic answers. 2) That's exactly what I'm saying. 3) If the range of values is fixed, of course you should use enums. But enums don't always cut it, that's the point of constants.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I tried noting it in the edit that it will not be used by clients or belongs to a hierarchy, sorry didn't do it early on. For #2, it seemed incorrect for any internal class to implement a constants interface just because it didn't seem to satisfy the is-a contract in the semantic sense. Agree with you on #3, thanks for pointing out.